# Add new line to a file contains <

Tags: sed

i am trying to add a new line to a file using sed :

```
sed -i '/<field name="Users" indexed="true"/>/a <copyField source="New_user" dest="text"/>' $RTDIR/schema.xml
```

i get an error:
unknown command: `>'

how can i make it work? and also, the change will be permanent?

Thanks!

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash in your the target string. You need to escape it with '\'
e.g.

```
sed -i '/<field name="Users" indexed="true"\/>/a <copyField source="New_user" dest="text"/>' $RTDIR/schema.xml
```